# Different MSBuild versions in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\MSBuild\v14.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

We have two developer PCs with (among other stuff) the most current version of Visual Studio 2019 (16.11.10) installed. On both PCs, the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\MSBuild\v14.0` contains the following DLLs:

```
Microsoft.Build.Conversion.Core.dll
Microsoft.Build.dll
Microsoft.Build.Engine.dll
Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll
Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll
```

However, the dates and versions differ:

- PC A has 2015-07-07 and 14.0.23107.0,
- PC B has 2016-06-20 and 14.0.25420.1.

This causes problems in our deployment process, because

1. we use a library (MS ReportViewer Control) that references Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll, and, thus, this DLL gets copied to the output directory and
2. our deployment tool complains when a build created with PC B is replaced by a (newer) build created with PC A, because one of the DLLs is actually older.

Now, I could just manually copy the DLLs from PC B to PC A, but this seems... dirty. After all, the DLLs were probably installed as part of some development tool, and I'd rather upgrade that development tool. However, as stated above, both PCs have exactly the same version of Visual Studio 2019 installed.

Is there some easy way to find out why the Reference Assemblies on PC A an PC B differ (apart for rebuilding one from scratch, which is definitely not worth the effort)?

Comment: Does both PC have the same update from Microsoft?  Looks like the updates from Microsoft are different.  The version of the reference libraries are in the proj file and the compile will complain when the versions in the proj do not match the version installed on amchine.

Comment: @jdweng: 1. What exactly do you mean by "the same update from Microsoft"? Both have the same VS version and all pending Windows Updates installed. 2. Unfortunately, the version is not in the proj file. It's a dependency of a dependency (MS ReportViewer Control), which references a very old version, so VS just takes the most up-to-date version it can find on the system.

Comment: Then remove the library in Solution Explorer and add so you get the latest library version installed.  The project file is not matching the version of Net installed.

Comment: @jdweng: I don't have the library in Solution Explorer. I don't reference the library at all. I reference `Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll` (of which I don't have the source), *which in turn* references `Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll` (without shipping it as part of the nuget package).

Comment: Where are you compiler instructions (equivalent to the proj file)?

Comment: @jdweng: I do have a proj file. It just doesn't reference `Microsoft.Build.Framework.dll`. msbuild automatically detects that one of my dependencies has an additional dependency and includes it in the project output.